# Is a compile-time split of &str possible?

Tags: rust

I'm creating a macro that does `include_bytes!` of a list of numbers separated by spaces:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

How can I create a slice of `u64` of those numbers at compile time? I tried converting to a string and then calling `split(" ")` but `split` iterates over it which is not `const`.

Comment: You can do this at compile time with a proc macro, but that seems overkill to me. What's the reason you want to do it at compile time?

Comment: You can try using this crate: https://crates.io/crates/uneval: “ In short, if you want to make some data in the human-readable format, such as JSON, to be deserialized at compile-time and build into the binary, as if it was written by hand, then this crate can possibly help you.”

Comment: Do you know the number of numbers ahead of times?

Comment: Equivalent URLO topic (containing an answer to the question IMO): https://users.rust-lang.org/t/is-compile-time-split-of-str-possible/91232

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [users.rust-lang](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/is-compile-time-split-of-str-possible/91232/8) forum answer provided a working solution: [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2c04dd792e6cf10f9d55025cf61a08d5)

```rs
const fn to_u64(bytes: &[u8], start: usize, end: usize) -> u64 {
    let mut res: u64 = 0;
    let mut i = start;

    while i < end {
        res = 10 * res + (bytes[i] - b'0') as u64;

        i += 1;
    }

    res
}

const fn split_parse<const LEN: usize>(bytes: &[u8]) -> [u64; LEN] {
    let mut res = [0; LEN];

    let mut idx_start = 0;
    let mut idx_curr = 0;
    let mut i = 0;

    while i < LEN {
        while idx_curr < bytes.len() && bytes[idx_curr] != b' ' {
            idx_curr += 1;
        }
        res[i] = to_u64(bytes, idx_start, idx_curr);
        idx_curr += 1;
        idx_start = idx_curr;
        i += 1;
    }

    res
}

const fn split_len(bytes: &[u8]) -> usize {
    let mut len = 1;
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < bytes.len() {
        if bytes[i] == b' ' {
            len += 1;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    len
}

const DATA: &[u8] = b"1 2 3 4 5";
// In the actual use case, you'd use include_bytes here
// const DATA: &[u8] = include_bytes!("numbers.txt");
const DATA_LEN: usize = split_len(DATA);
static DATA_INTS: [u64; DATA_LEN] = split_parse(DATA);

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", DATA_INTS);
}
```

This solution uses const functions instead of a macro. It assumes the input is valid, but if you want to validate the input, you can use `panic`. For example, inside `to_u64` you can check if the character is a number:

```rs
if b'0' > bytes[i] || b'9' < bytes[i] {
    panic!("Not an integer");
}
```